# Using "self" in externally called method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main View Controller (ViewControllerA) which has a container with a child View Controller (ViewControllerB) inside with a few labels and buttons. During the app's usage, `NSUserDefaults` will change and the labels in ViewControllerB need to be updated (simplified version).

I've got a method inside the ViewControllerB's class file which I can access from ViewControllerA however calling the method does not update the labels which I suspect is due to the `self` reference. The method definitely fires and I've included ViewControllerB's class in the header of ViewControllerA etc.

```
- (void)testingMethod{        
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"firstValue"]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"firstValue"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"secondValue"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Never" forKey:@"thirdValue"];
    }
    self.firstLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"firstValue"];
    self.secondLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"secondValue"];
    self.thirdLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"thirdValue"];
}
```

The method is called from an `IBAction` from within ViewControllerA's class like so:

```
- (IBAction)doThis:(id)sender{
    ViewControllerB * something;
    something = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
    [something testingMethod];
}
```

My question then is how can I get those labels to change when calling that method from outside the class it was created in?

Interface builder example screenshot:
[image]
When the button is clicked, the label in the child view should update.

Comment: Do you call this method on the same instance that the one displayed ? Can you show the part where you call this method?

Comment: I've edited my question to show the calling method from ViewControllerA's .m file. That should hopefully give you some insight.

Comment: Ah! How are you moving from A to B? Are you using a segue? Can you show the code of how you're moving from A to B please.

Comment: Not *really* moving from A to B. B is an embedded `UIViewController` that's embedded inside a container within ViewControllerA.

Comment: Ah ok, will edit my answer. Is it in a container view from a storyboard?

Comment: @ScottMcGready i am not sure but are you saving the contents using the synchronize method of NSUserDefaults?

Comment: @vin it's nothing to do with the `NSUserDefaults` (although you raise a good point). I've hardcoded the labels to just a string rather than `NSUserDefaults` in order to check that but still it doesn't update.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Ok ,do you have a segue identifier for the above? If so then you should try 
prepareForSegue Method and do something like
self.containerViewController=segue.destinationViewController

Comment: @Justafinger posted that solution not too long ago. Took us a while to get there but we got it in the end - cheers for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call the testingMethod on the same instance than the one displayed. You need to have an ivar declared in your ViewController A, then you would have something like this

In ViewController A.h

```
@class ViewControllerB;

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
{
    ViewControllerB *viewControllerB;
}
```

In ViewController A.m

```
//Add this method to get the viewControllerB instance
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    //This identifier is set in the storyboard, in the attribute inspector of the segue
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueVCB"])
    {
        viewControllerB = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}

- (IBAction)doThis:(id)sender{
    [viewControllerB testingMethod];
}
```

Basically, imagine your viewControllerA is your car and viewControllerB is your headlights. You want to turn on the headlights by clicking a button. You added correctly the headlights to your car, but when you click the button you create another headlight that is never added and you expect the one on your car to lights on. That does not make any sense. You need to have one pair of headlights and to activate those when you click the button.

Comment: That seems to result in an error unfortunately: `Receiver type 'ViewControllerB' for instance message is a forward declaration`
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you imported ViewControllerB.h ?

Comment: Indeed got a few other oddities that definitely don't make sense. Give me a second and I'll give Xcode the good ol' fashioned switch it off and back on again.

Comment: Okay, it compiles without errors now which is great... but doesn't update the labels. Interesting. The method is definitely firing (using `NSLog` to check).

Comment: Do you see the view of viewControllerB correctly ? What if you set self.thirdLabel.text = @"Test" or add it in your viewDidLoad, can you see "Test" ? You can also set a breakpoint in testingMethod and check that your labels are not null.

Comment: Hardcoded it to `@"test"` and that didn't fly. It's odd because the method is definitely firing but the text isn't changing on the label. For reference the child view was always loaded. Love the analogy of the car btw.

Comment: Glad it was helpful ;). I believe your labels are null. How do you add them to your view (using interface builder, programmatically)?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to show the rough outline in IB. I am using Interface Builder to do most of the legwork.

Comment: Have you link your UILabel in IB to firstLabel ? It is by the way strange that you have 3 labels in your ViewControllerB but only one added in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Yep have indeed. Yeah I just did a mockup quickly. Still no joy. Man this is proving to be insanely annoying.

Comment: Well i'm starting to run out of ideas. I don't experience any issue with it. Can you print the output of NSLog(@"%@",self.firstLabel); ?

Comment: Sure, I am too: `2014-04-07 12:23:27.895 TestProj[3588:60b] (null)`

Comment: Ok so that's why it is not updating, it is null. You probably have not linked the outlets correctly in IB. Click on ViewControllerB (yellow icon in the top left corner of your screenshot). On the right in the Connections Inspector (last icon), you should see your outlets defined in ViewControllerB.h like this `@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UILabel *firstLabel;`

Comment: Nah man, they're all correct. Here, I've uploaded the test project to dropbox - you can see for yourself everything is correctly connected and set up as expected. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51769489/test.zip

Comment: Oh god, i feel a bit dumb. I've edited my answer for a working solution. I don't usually use storyboard so there might be a better option. The problem is that a storyboard creates also an instance of viewController B which is not the same as the one you create in viewDidLoad. So you don't need to create a new one, you just get the one created by the storyboard with prepareForSegue.

Comment: I owe you a beer/coffee sir. It works! That one was a stumped moment and a half.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `objectForKey` instead of `stringForKey`.

I don't think (not 100%) that they're interchangeable in the way you are using them.

**EDIT**

OK, the way you're accessing `ViewControllerB` is not correct. You are creating a completely fresh instance of it.

You might have ViewControllerB as a subview/child view controller but that isn't what you're running the method on.

You need to get the child view controller and run the method on that. @Justafinger was quicker than me. Do what he said.

Comment: Even trying stuff like `self.firstLabel.text = @"hardcodedString";` doesn't fly. The `stringForKey` I'll update though, can't believe I missed that!